# Camping in Hakone (I bring my tent)

Tags: japan, camping

Is it possible to camp in Hakone?

Most Google results for "camping hakone" are lodges, not the tent thing. I am looking for real camping, it should be free or cost less than 1000 yen.

In case camping anywhere is OK, I guess there are places where it is more usual for campers to go than on the lawn in front of the lake?

- Hakone has many great public baths so shower is not needed.
- No electricity needed. Water appreciated.
- It can be far away from any road, as I will be hiking.

Comment: Indeed, "free" is "less than 1000 yen"...

Comment: I always camp anywhere in Japan (almost) for a single night. I set up at night and pack up early. Even in the smaller cities. I'm never sure of the actual rules but never got in trouble doing this from Okinawa to Soya Misaki. When staying multiple days in the same town I tend to change camping spots each night.

Answer (score 4):

The only campsites with facilities that I'm able to find near Hakone are:

- [Ashinoko Camp Mura](http://campmura.com/price_accommodation/), right on Lake Ashinoko, which charges ¥1000-2000 depending on season for a tent space (テントサイト) and is accessible by public transport
- [Gotenba Otome Forest Camp #1](http://gotemba-otome.jp/camp1/tentsite.html), which is a flat ¥2000 all year round and is close to inaccessible without your own wheels

See [Is free camping permitted in Japan?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/25016/is-free-camping-permitted-in-japan?rq=1) for wild camping in Japan.  Hakone is pretty built up, touristy and commercialized, so I'd hesitate to recommend it here though.